# WebPage Prints in two print pages

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I want to print a page on my website via javascript, but it prints in two pages instead of one. What should I change?

All my CSS is inline.

```
window.print();
```

Here is my HTML: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8qj6/)

Its only table based, but it still is not working. There is no height assigned to it.

Comment: Maybe it is because it is too high to print on one page?

Comment: I want to print it on one page,what should i do? its not too much...

Comment: umm.. get a bigger paper..  ._.

Comment: If you look at my html,it is not too big...i have same page contents in pdf..which is on one page

Comment: PDFs control margins, web pages use the defaults. Webpages can not control the printer.

Comment: @epascarello:   What is the solution? What should i do now?

Comment: Perhaps you could [convert the webpage to PDF](https://www.google.com/search?q=turn+webpage+into+pdf&oq=turn+webpage+into+pdf&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5058j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: CSS print media, add CSS to shrink your stuff.

Comment: I want to find a way to do through coding...any jquery plugin?

Comment: @epascarello:I am using inline css..i have no css tag.how to shrink it via css?

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and look up "CSS Print Media"

Answer (score 0):

A screen has 72ppi, creating things in HTML sticks to this rule as it is on screen so the only thing you can really do is reduce the amount that's in your table or print-screen your table and print it as an image so you can re-size it.

Comment: I can not print screen it,still hides something...a scroll down must needed...do we have an option in programing in js?